# How do I transfer a variable in the "Values" section to the "Data" section in R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Within R-Studio there are two headers within the Global Environment for "Data" and "Values". For some reason, one of my vectors is listed in the "Values" section and I need to transfer it to the "Data" section.

It appears as the variable "test" with a description of " num [1:51] 0 2 4 6 ...". I assume there is an easy way to transfer this to the "Data" section, but I have yet to find a solution.

Comment: Rstudio separates out data frames(and other table type objects) from other data objects.  This has no effect beyond that display.  Why do you need it to be in the data section? Or what do you need to do with this object?

Comment: All vectors and lists will be listed under "Values" and all dataframes and matrices will be listed under "Data". You can convert the vector to a matrix like `matrix(test)` to have it displayed under "Data", but like @Ian Wesley brought up, not sure why you would want to do that.

Comment: I was trying to see the full list of numbers within the "test" variable. Whenever I try view(test) it only lists "num [1:51] 0 2 4 6 ...".

Comment: Then what about just typing `test` in your console...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your vector to a data frame using `test <- as.data.frame(test)`. that way, you can `View()` to see the whole list. You could also print the vector in the console by just typing the name of the vector (test) in the console and hitting enter, this would show the data contained in the vector without changing the format.